# Alguien sabe por qué al usar PHP con CSS y HTml (include y requier) los estilos de mezclan

Tags: php, html, css, html5

Estoy haciendo una página en el que reciclo varios archi
vos usando requiere e include (php), pero al incluir esos archivos aparecen con los estilos mezclados. Por ejemplo tengo un archivo con una tabla con bordes color rojo y otro archivo con otra que si pasas el ratón por encima el background se vuelve azul. Al incluir las dos en el index se hace una mezcla de esos dos. ¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Comment: Quizá se debe a que en los CSS no tienes claro cómo deben aplicarse los estilos, qué prioridad debe aplicarse, etc, lo que hace que se sobre-escriban o se entrecrucen.

Comment: @A.Cedano puede que sea eso, ya que si se entrecruzan, me podrías ayudar con algún video o algo?

Comment: No tengo ninguna referencia a vídeos que expliquen esto, soy de la vieja escuela, de los que aprendimos a programar leyendo libros y más tarde tutoriales. Es cuestión de comprender cómo funciona CSS, las reglas se aplican en cascada, hay prioridades en los selectores y cuando una regla con prioridad superior la pones al final del archivo ésta rompe toda la cascada. Sabiendo eso, tendrás que organizar tus clases/selectores de modo que la cascada no se rompa y una regla no sobre-escriba a otra. Hay varios estilos de escritura CSS que pueden ayudarte a mantener el código organizado.

Comment: Hay que googlear un poco https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS

Comment: Publica el código, de esa forma te podemos ayudar mejor.